# Can ZeroMQ work in a concurrent multithread mode on a single port?

Tags: .net, multithreading, zeromq

I have a simple Server running:

```
        using (var context = ZmqContext.Create())
        using (var socket = context.CreateSocket(SocketType.REP)) {

            Console.WriteLine("Starting on {0}", tcpAddress);

            socket.Bind(tcpAddress);

            while (true) {
                var replyMessage = socket.Receive((Encoding.Unicode));
                Console.WriteLine("Received: [{0}]", replyMessage);

                // Do some stuff

                socket.Send(string.Format("Received [{0}]", replyMessage), Encoding.Unicode);                            
            }     
        }
```

And when I use a client to request info, it returns fine, but when multiple clients hit the server, the requests are queued up, and are waiting for the Server to respond because it can only process one request at a time.

Is there a way to make this ZeroMQ server be able to listen on the tcpaddress for multiple client requests and handle them concurrently?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a simple request/response multi-threaded server based on the example in the [zeromq guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall#Multithreading-with-MQ).

The code from the guide:
https://github.com/imatix/zguide/blob/master/examples/C%23/mtserver.cs

However, the solution is not very scalable.

Comment: Thanks Luke, I did something similar using SmartThreadPool, but wondered if there was something more generic and scalable.  If I have to, I'll roll my own similar to what you suggested.